# Wordpress "Error establishing database connection" and showing a different DB hostname

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress site hosted with GoDaddy.  It's a company site and I'm not a developer, just an employee with enough knowledge to try to troubleshoot the issue.

A week ago the site worked fine.  Yesterday they discovered that attempting to access the site shows "Error establishing database connection".  Looking at wp-config, it shows a db hostname that doesn't match the hostname in CPanel.  The hostname is listed as p3plcpnl1046.prod.phx3.secureserver.net however the server in CPanel shows p3plmcpnl487504.

If I switch the hostname to 'localhost' or to the hostname shown in CPanel, the site loads and connects to that database but that database is out-of-date by 2 years.  Viewing that sql database in PHPMyAdmin I can see it contains outdated information including content that was deleted / edited over the last 2 years.

As best I can tell, the wp-config file was not recently edited prior to my edits yesterday.  GoDaddy support has been less than helpful figuring out what happened to the current version of the database and doesn't seem to understand that the auto-generated wp-config was showing an entirely different hostname.  They've escalated the ticket to their engineers.

Any idea what's going on here?  Thanks for any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: Usually godaddy include periodical backups.  Asking support to find them may be the best path.  Wordpress is an application with vulnerabilities that need to be patched aggressively.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  We did that but there only seems to be a single backup from yesterday after the issue had already occurred.  Support thought that was odd as there should be 30 days worth of backups apparently.